# Show that S is not a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function. Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $S$ denote the set $\left\{\operatorname{Re}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)+\operatorname{Im}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)\,\middle|\,z\in \Omega\right\}$.

I want to show that $S$ is not a discrete subset of $R$? How should I do that?

I know $f$ is continuous, $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ is continuous. I think I can use this to prove my claim. But I am not able to think further.

Comment: I suppose that you meant $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))+\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ instead of $\operatorname{Re}(f(z)+\operatorname{Im}(f(z)$.

Comment: Yes. Please tell me Latex command

Comment: I've edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is true if and only if $f$ is not constant.

So, assuming that $f$ is not constant: pick any disk $D \subset \omega$. Since $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))+\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ is continuous, and $D$ is connected, $(\operatorname{Re}(f(z))+\operatorname{Im}(f(z)))(D)$ is connected.

Assuming now that $S$ is discrete, it follows that $(\operatorname{Re}(f(z))+\operatorname{Im}(f(z)))(D)$ is connected and discrete thus a single point. This means that $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))+\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ is constant on $D$.

This shows that $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))=C-\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ on $D$. Setting as usual $u=\operatorname{Re}(f(z)), v=\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ by Cauchy-Riemann we get
$$v=C-u \\
u_x=v_y=-u_y\\
u_y=-v_x=u_x
$$
and thus
$$u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$$
meaning $f$ is constant.

Comment: This was so simple. I know all these results but I was not able to use them. I think I should work more on solving problems and learn how to implement basic result. thank a lot. I will be glad if you can give me some advice.

Comment: @MathamanTopologius Well, I think you gave yourself the advice: this "skill
usually comes from experience, and the experience comes from solving more problems ;)

Comment: This is not correct. By that argument, $f(z)=\operatorname{Re}(z)-\operatorname{Re}(z)i$ would be constant.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I did not get it. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @MathamanTopologius The argument used by N. S. doesn't really use the fact that $f$ is entire. Therefore, it should hold for every continuous function but, as my example shows, it doesn't.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It would be great if you can write an answer for this question. Thank you

Comment: @MathamanTopologius What for? You already have [this on](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2902045/446262). I can't improve on that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, stupid mistake on my part, fixed now :)

Comment: @MathamanTopologius Jose is right, my original answer replaced at some point $\operatorname{Re}(f(z))+\operatorname{Im}(f(z))$ by $f$, now I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f$ is not constant. The function
$$\psi:\quad\Omega\to{\mathbb R},\qquad z\mapsto{\rm Re}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)+{\rm Im}\bigl(f(z)\bigr)$$
is continuous, hence maps $\Omega$ to a connected set $S\subset{\mathbb R}$. Furthermore $\psi=\phi\circ f$, where $\phi$ denotes the map
$$\phi:\quad(u,v)\mapsto u+v\ .$$
Both $f$ and $\phi$ map open sets to open sets, hence $S=\psi(\Omega)$ is open. Altogether it follows that $S$ is a (bounded) open interval.